# Configuring a windows jenkins slave to use proper Grails tools location?

Tags: windows, grails, hudson, jenkins

I have an ubuntu jenkins master and a windows jenkins slave.

I have one `Build with Grails` command, and I choose

`GRAILS_137`, which on the master is set to `/opt/tools/grails-1.3.7/`

I don't see anywhere to configure the slave to set the grails location. How do I do this? When this build runs on windows, it does this:

`cmd.exe /C /opt/Tools/grails-1.3.7/bin/grails`

How do I configure the grails location for the windows slave jenkins? Trying to configure `Node options` of the slave from the master only lets me select `JDK`, `Git`, and `Gradle` locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grails plugin has no support for slaves.